# How would you handle subscriptions and recurring payments using Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am building a VOD site using Craft and Craft Commerce. This is the first time I'm working with their Commerce plugin.

I would like to:

1. Create subscription products and assign them to plan types.
2. Subscription period of any duration and frequency.
3. Trial period to lower a price barrier for subscribers.
4. Payments processed via external gateways.

What is the best way of implementing such functionality?

Answer (score 4):

At time of writing (22/08/16) - there is no support for subscriptions in Commerce.  You could attempt to do them as traditional products but I suspect it would be a lot of custom work.

It's a *very frequently* [requested feature](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/295386-commerce/suggestions/7814868-subscriptions) and I suspect proper subscriptions support will come to Commerce sooner rather than later.  Hopefully much sooner!

In the meantime, the solution most people seem to talk about is the Charge plugin instead of Commerce (or alongside Commerce for other commerce needs): https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge